# Get-Service parameter binding not working as expected

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm learning PowerShell and have a question on parameter binding. It's probably a simple question, but I'm at a loss.

If I type:

```
get-adcomputer -filter 'name -eq "serverone"' |
  select @{name='computername';e={$_.name}} |
  get-process
```

that gives me a list of processes on "serverone" and works fine.  But if I type:

```
get-adcomputer -filter 'name -eq "serverone"' |
  select @{name='computername';e={$_.name}} |
  get-service
```

then I get the following error:

```
get-service : Cannot find any service with service name
'@{computername=SERVERONE}'. At line:1 char:93
+ ... e={$_.name}} | get-service
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{computername=SERVERONE}:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Why is this?  Both `Get-Process` and `Get-Service` accept computername, and the help files for this parameter look identical.  Interestingly, if I type the same code but add `-Name bits` to the `Get-Service` command above, it comes back with the service details.  So it looks like `Get-Service` is trying to bind the object to the service name, but that doesn't happen with `Get-Process` which looks very similar in syntax?!

Answer (score 5):

You feed pipeline input into `Get-Service` without any other parameters, so the pipelined objects are passed to the first parameter accepting them, which is `-Name`. Since the objects don't have a property `Name` they're passed in their entirety and cast to strings, so they appear as `@{computername=SERVERONE}`. `Get-Service` then looks for a service with that name, which of course fails, causing the error you observed.

Parameter definitions for `Get-Service` (relevant characteristics in italics):

```
PS C:\> Get-Help Get-Service -Parameter Name

-Name 
    Specifies the service names of services to be retrieved. Wildcards
    are permitted. By default, Get-Service gets all of the services on
    the computer.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    1
    Default value                All services
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName, ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  true

PS C:\> Get-Help Get-Service -Parameter ComputerName

-ComputerName 
    Gets the services running on the specified computers. The default
    is the local computer.

    Type the NetBIOS name, an IP address, or a fully qualified domain
    name of a remote computer. To specify the local computer, type the
    computer name, a dot (.), or "localhost".

    This parameter does not rely on Windows PowerShell remoting. You
    can use the ComputerName parameter of Get-Service even if your
    computer is not configured to run remote commands.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                Local computer
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Parameter definitions for `Get-Process` (relevant characteristics in italics):

```
PS C:\> Get-Help Get-Process -Parameter Name

-Name 
    Specifies one or more processes by process name. You can type
    multiple process names (separated by commas) and use wildcard
    characters. The parameter name ("Name") is optional.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    1
    Default value
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  true

PS C:\> Get-Help Get-Process -Parameter ComputerName

-ComputerName 
    Gets the processes running on the specified computers. The default
    is the local computer.

    Type the NetBIOS name, an IP address, or a fully qualified domain
    name of one or more computers. To specify the local computer, type
    the computer name, a dot (.), or "localhost".

    This parameter does not rely on Windows PowerShell remoting. You
    can use the ComputerName parameter of Get-Process even if your
    computer is not configured to run remote commands.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                Local computer
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

As you can see there *is* a difference in the definition of the `-Name` parameter between the two cmdlets. `Get-Service` accepts pipeline input for `-Name` not only by property name, but also by value, while `Get-Process` does not. That is why `Get-Process` handles your pipeline input as intended, whereas `Get-Service` doesn't.

To avoid this problem, you need to specify which service(s) you want to get. Use `*` for all services. With the `-Name` parameter specified the computer names are passed to the `-ComputerName` parameter by property name as you intended:

```psh
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -eq "serverone"' |
  select @{n='ComputerName';e={$_.Name}} |
  Get-Service -Name *
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write that, that's really helpful

Comment: Now I've had a chance to go through this, I'm still a little unclear on why Get-Service and Get-Process handles the parameters sent over differently.  Unlike Get-Service, Get-Process doesn't treat them as process names, despite having a name and computername parameter in the same positions.  You're saying that the fact that Get-Service accepts pipeline input ByValue is the difference, but why exactly is this?

Comment: What do you mean "why"? Because the parameter was defined to accept input by value. You'll have to ask Microsoft why it was defined that way.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  I guess this has just highlighted my lack of understanding on what 'ByValue' exactly means.  As I said, I'm currently learning.

Answer (score 0):

An cmdlet has parameter sets (1 or more).

Get-Service has 3: **Default**, **DisplayName** and **InputObject**.

Unfortunately, you're not using any of them, which explains why PowerShell complains about something.

You could use the available parameter sets this way:

- **InputObject**: it requires a `ServiceController` type object, which is not your case.
- **DisplayName**: This one requires that you specify the parameter name, **explicitely**, like in:

`1 |`
`select @{l='computername';e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}} |`
`gsv -DisplayName 'your-service's-display-name'`

- **Default**: This is probably the one that matches your code. This parameter set allows you pass the **ComputerName** parameter either as an object property, or as a positional parameter. For instance:

**1- As a positional parameter:**

`1 |`
`select @{l='computername';e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}} |`
`gsv alg # 'alg' is the service name; you can choose some other(s)`

**2- As an object parameter:**

`1 |`
`select @{l='name';e={'alg'}},@{l='computername';e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}} |`
`gsv`

Notice that this last one resembles your code very much. The important difference is that I'm defining the object's property **Name** (besides **ComputerName**) which you are not.

Comment: Thank you, I will play with that.